# jquery ajax not passing parameters

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've used ajax before, but this time the ajax is not passing the parameters, I've already tried some solutions, but can't solve this.

jQuery

```
 $('.entrar').click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        if (check_login()){

            var dataLogin;
            var manter_ligado;

            if ($('#mantem_login').is(':checked'))
            {
                manter_ligado = "1";
            } else {
                manter_ligado = "0";
            }

            dataLogin = 'mail=' + $('#login_mail').val() + '&pass=' + $('#login_password').val() + '&on=' + manter_ligado;

            $.ajax({
                  url: 'modules/login.php',
                  type: 'POST',
                  //data: dataLogin,
                  data : ({
                            mail : $('#login_mail').val(),
                            pass : $('#login_password').val(),
                            on : manter_ligado
                         }),
                  success: function(data) {
                    alert('Login efectuado com sucesso.');
                    console.log(data);
                  },
                  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Login nao entrou');
                    console.log(xhr.statusText);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(error);
                  }
                });

            return false;

        }

    })
```

this is HTML

```
        <span class="title">Entrar na sua conta</span>

        <input name="login_mail" placeholder=" e-mail" id="login_mail" type="email" class="email text_box"/>
        <input name="login_password" placeholder="password" id="login_password" type="password" class="password text_box" />
        <span>Perdeu a password?</span>

        <div class="mantem_login">
            <input name="mantem_login" id="mantem_login" type="checkbox" class="mantem_login" />
            <label for="mantem_login"><span class="mantem_login">Manter-me conectado</span></label>
        </div>


        <input type="submit" name="entrar" class="submit_button entrar" id="entrar" value=""  />

    </div>
</form>
```

What can I do so that the parameters get to the url?

Comment: Despite the answers below, the parenthesis are not the cause of this problem (though they are unnecessary). We need more info. How do you know the params aren't getting sent? You're using post, yet you talk about them getting into the URL. Look in the network log when the request is sent - do you see the params sent or not?

Comment: Ok, I just saw that I had and early version of my code there. 
I was sending the post by data this way:
`dataLogin = 'mail=' + $('#login_mail').val() + '&pass=' + $('#login_password').val() + '&on=' + manter_ligado; 
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'modules/login.php',
    type: 'POST', 
    data: dataLogin, 
...` 
I have another ajax on this page and it works, using the same type of code, but for this one, I can't get the post values. As for the way to get them, I want them to get passed by URL, so that I can get them after.

Comment: There is not enough info in your question for us to help you. The code you posted WILL send post vars. You do not show the server side code that tries to receive them. I'm also confused when you say you want to pass them in the URL. POST values are not sent in the request URL (that's GET) - they are sent dedicatedly. Again, consult your browser's network log when you fire the request. If you see the params being sent (you will), the issue is with how you are trying to receive them on the server.

Comment: @Utkanos Ok, I've seen that, and it was a mistake of mine, thanks for the help. I can't give you the points for the help, sorry for that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the round brackets from your parameter value:

```
data: {
    mail : $('#login_mail').val(),
    pass : $('#login_password').val(),
    on : manter_ligado
}
```